# Android UI Thread Performance Issue

Tags: android, android-view

I have n number of views in my activity. Some views in the activity will be updated(like text change, bg..etc..) using timer very instantly. i.e **more than 50 views per second.**

App get hangs when I try to access some other views(i.e scrolling ListView or GridView) when UI update happens.

Any idea to increase UI performance ?

Comment: what timer? how do you use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use other threads to do work that don't interact directly with the user interface and then send the results to the ui thread who will just update your views. 
You can use basic threads or other higher level classes (asynctask, handlers).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your question has a very broad scope. You might want to narrow down your requirement as per your code. Here are a few generic pointers to keep in mind.

1) Methods/Procedures that do not require UI interaction for a major part of its lifetime should be executed in a background thread(Async Task,Threads etc).Followed up with updating UI if required based on their result.[See](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

2) Make sure you use recyclable views like listview and expandablelistview coupled with [Viewholder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) Pattern wherever possible to avoid too many views to be managed at runtime.

Primarily ,if you see stuff like "skipped  frames.Your activity might be doing too much work on its main thread.." in your logcat , its a direct pointer to offload a  few operations from the UI to a background thread.

Hope you can make sense of this abstract information.

Comment: I'm will be receiving more data from TCP Socket. instantly i need to update those data's in view. All the parsing method and connections are handled in asynctask already.. If i check without UI update, app works fine.

Comment: Then most certainly you're holding a lot of views in the memory at a time.spill out some code here. So that it becomes a bit more meaningful